# Should I put newlines before or after binary operators?

Tags: c++, coding-style

When you're in Python or Javascript, you should always put binary operators at the *end* of the previous line, in order to prevent newlines from terminating your code prematurely; it helps you catch errors.

But in C or C++, this isn't an issue, so I'm wondering:

Is there any reason for me to prefer the second version to the first?

```
return lots_of_text
       + 1;
```

versus

```
return lots_of_text +
       1;
```

(For example, does one of them help prevent other kinds of errors? Or is one of them considered more readable?)

Comment: No you shouldn't do that in Python, mostly because does not have the effect you claim it has. A trailing operator doesn't cause a line continuation; a backslash or having unclosed parentheses, brackets or braces does.

Comment: @delnan: I (very carefully) never said it *causes* a line continuation. I'm aware you still need enclosing grouping characters. I said it helps prevent mistakes with your line ending prematurely, which it does, by giving you an error.

Comment: I see, but it doesn't do that either. At least I've never seen it happen (and I strictly follow PEP 8's rule about putting newlines after operators) and I cannot imagine non-contrived code which is valid with the newline before the operator but not after the operator. For example, code like in your first snippet also errors (due to indentation). Does anyone not add indentations when splitting a line?

Comment: @delnan: It's actually very easy to accidentally screw up the indentation with your text editor, e.g. when bulk-editing or doing rectangular selection. And if/when that happens during maintenance, you won't get an error in the first case and it will silently slip by you, but you'll get a nice error in the second case.

Comment: I don't know about you, but I rarely screw up indentation anywhere but the single line I currently work on, and when I do, I'm told by a ludicrously long diff and by syntax errors. Speaking of which, how many of those mishaps leave all your code in a state where it's accepted by the parser? (Let alone a style guide checker.) All things considered, I still believe it's incredibly unlikely to wind up with valid but wrong code due to *this*.

Comment: @delnan: I'm not kidding when I say it's easy to make the mistake. It's happened to me. Just set your editor to 8 spaces per tab, with tab-based indentation, and open a 4-*space*-indented file it. If (for whatever reason) it doesn't detect things correctly, and you try un-indenting a block of code and "fixing" it by re-indenting, you'll see this sort of code will get messed up upon un-indenting.  It really slips by me quite easily, but if you or your colleagues never run into problems like this, more power to you I guess.

Comment: Okay, bad luck then. But I was just wondering: If it (i.e. an expression across multiple lines) worked before the indentation mix-up, wouldn't it need cross-line parens/brackets/braces (or a line continuation character) anyway? If so, I'd say one *can't* introduce this error just by breaking indentation, as these would keep it a multi-line expression, or at least cause an error due to being imbalanced. Please show me the error in my reasoning.

Comment: @delnan: Oh, you're definitely right about that -- there isn't any 'error' with your reasoning, it's just a bit short-sighted. :-) You're assuming that (1) there is only supposed to be *a single* mistake that leads to errors, or that (2) people make predictable mistakes when writing code. (For example, you're completely ignoring the use of regexes in a text editor -- I use them often, and every once in a while they cause errors like this.) The bottom line is that this is more error-*prone* in general (at least for me, maybe not for you), **not** that it's just one step away from correct code.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted. It seems like a reasonable coding style question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Line break before/after operator](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/93670/line-break-before-after-operator)

Comment: @delnan: pep8 has been updated: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#should-a-line-break-before-or-after-a-binary-operator

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As you can see from the answers, there is no consensus on this matter. Unless you work in a team, use what **you** are more comfortable with.

---

*I* prefer inserting a newline before operators.

Whenever I have to break lines, I usually put at most one term of the same "level" on a line:

Newton's law of gravitation in Python:

```
force = (
    gravitational_constant
    * mass_1
    * mass_2
    / (distance * distance)
)
```

Compare this to:

```
force = (
    gravitational_constant *
    mass_1 *
    mass_2 /
    (distance * distance)
)
```

I want to know, that I "divide **by** distance squared", I don't want to know, that "mass_2 **gets** divided", because that's not how I think of mathematical expressions.

<sub>Further, I usually want to know first, *what* I am doing (operator), before I care about what I *do things with* (operands).</sub>

Or consider this convoluted SQL statement:

```
WHERE
  a = 1
  AND b = 2
  AND c = 3
  AND ( -- or put the OR on one line together with the AND
    d = 3 
    OR e = 1)
  AND x = 5
```

This allows me to see how the individual conditions are connected very easily, just by skimming from top to bottom without having to read every line until the end to find the operator as opposed to:

```
WHERE
  a = 1 AND
  b = 2 AND
  c = 3 AND
  ( 
    d = 3 OR
    e = 1) AND
  x = 5
```

I think about the former in terms of "`X` is true", then I amend that by saying: "**AND** this is also true" which *feels* more natural to me than the other way around. Further, I find the first much easier to parse visually.

Or a PHP example:

```
$text = "lorem ipsum"
      . "dolor sit amet, "
      . "consectetur adipisicing elit, "
      . "sed do eiusmod tempor";
```

Again, I can just skim read vertically to see I'm simply concatenating text, because most of the time I feel that I do not actually care what is inside the strings/conditions.

Of course, I would not apply this style unconditionally. If putting the newline after an operator seems to make more sense to me, I would do so, but I can't think of an example at the moment.

Comment: Added missing parenthesis to first example.

Comment: +1: exactly right; mathematics is always typeset so that continuation lines start with an operator.

Comment: +1 for the same reasons you describe, but your PHP example looks _quite_ odd to me.  Shouldn't those concats just be `.`, not `.=` ?

Comment: @Izkata oh yes, you are correct of course. Thanks. kevin: The parentheses were correct ;) I just aligned them with `force`

Answer (score 14):

I almost always break lines **before** binary operators in order to make clear to readers of the code that this is the continuation of an expression and not the next statement. This is important if the next statement would normally be indented. For example, consider an **if** statement that has a complex conditional expression:

```
if (first_part_of_condition &&
    second_part_of_condition) {
    statement_within_then_part;
}
```

The second part of the conditional expression is easily confused with the first statement of the then-part. This can be quite confusing if the first part of the condition is long and the && ends up way off to the right. Compare this with the alternative:

```
if (first_part_of_condition
    && second_part_of_condition) {
    statement_within_then_part;
}
```

This looks a bit odd but it makes it quite clear that the second part of the condition is not the beginning of a statement.

I do this in others contexts too but the if-statement is the most important, as the indentation is ambiguous. Of course, one could change the indentation or brace placement, but this looks odd too.

tl;dr the left end of the line is more significant to quick reading comprehension, so putting the operator on the left end is a more prominent marker that this is a continued expression, not a statement.

Comment: Interesting thought but I stil find this pretty confusing (especially when done with `+` and `-` which could also be understood as unary prefix operators). The usual solution to make the continuing lines stand out is to indent them *more* (i.e. by two levels).

Comment: "The second part of the conditional expression is easily confused with the first statement of the then-part.": This does not happen if you align the "{" and "}" vertically (same column) to make the beginning and the end of the block stand out more clearly.

Answer (score 10):

I'd always use the first. You want it to be clear what you are doing with that 1 there. If I saw that and there was a wall of text above that 1 I'd have no idea what was going on as far as that 1's usage.

```
# The first
return lots_of_text
       + 1;
```

The '+' being next to 1 makes it clear that at a minimum I am doing something with the 1 in question rather than it hanging out going "I'm all in your code dude..." for no apparent reason.

Comment: seconded...........

Answer (score 8):

I feel that it helps reading comprehension tremendously when a line indicates that the statement continues in the next line by having the binary operator at the end, and thus rendering the statement incomplete. The missing semicolon isn’t enough for me to immediately understand that.

This may simply be a question of habit but unless you work exclusively in languages which require the semicolon (which I find pretty unrealistic given the pervasiveness of shell scripts, makefiles and languages such as Python) you probably won’t have that habit either.

EDIT: Giorgio makes an excellent point in the comments: *this usage echoes common punctuation*, both in mathematics and natural languages. You’d write

> I sink,
>   therefore I swam

You would *not* write

> I sink
>   , therefore I swam

Comment: +1: I also tend to read the + at the end of the line as a comma separating two items in a list of operands. For this reason I prefer to put the + at the end of a line as I would do with a comma (I would never start a line with a comma).

Comment: @Giorgio This point is so excellent that I’ve stolen it for my answer. I hope you can forgive me.

Comment: Go ahead: I feel honoured. ;-)

Comment: Code is not English, and I think it's a false analogy to use English syntax rules as a way to justify coding conventions. I don't like the trailing operator style, but I admit Konrad has a good point about languages like Python.

Comment: @emddudley It’s not an analogy at all. It’s just adapting practices you’re used to anyway. Programming languages adapt the conventions of spoken languages *all the time*.

Comment: In mathematical typesetting, the line break is always before an operator, never after.  In the prosaic example, the operator is "therefore".  In English prose, commas are essentially breath marks.

Comment: If I programmed the way I write prose, I would never get anywhere. This is a bad justification. Also with math, it really depends on where I put a break. Depends on the operator and whether it applies more to one of the sides or not at all. For example, with implication, I would put it the line break before it. The main reason I (usually) do the line break before the operator is so that it is immediately clear the expression part is part of a bigger whole and not its own statement for example.

Comment: @emddudley と I は agree.  ;)

Comment: @kevincline Your claim about mathematical typesetting is simply incorrect. It may certainly depend on language and culture, but I can’t remember having seen a *single* instance of that, and in fact where i come from formulae are *always* broken *after* the operator (which is sometimes repeated in the next line, but it appears that this practice is waning) – except for relational operators.

Comment: @Konrad: perhaps it depends on publisher.  I'm looking at my copy of "Production Planning by Mixed Integer Programming" from Springer and multi-line expressions are broken before the operator.  I'll look at some more texts when I get home.